# If statement being skipped while asynchronously writing and zipping PDFs in large datasets

Tags: javascript, pdf, asynchronous

So I'm parsing large CSV files into arrays and generating PDFs from them then zipping them in my React app. I'm using [PDF-LIB](https://pdf-lib.js.org/) for PDF form filling and [JSZip](https://stuk.github.io/jszip/) for zipping. Many of the save functions are asynchronous with both libraries. I have an if statement that checks if a certain column is equal to something sandwiched between other code.

```
let count = 0;
const formPdfBytes = await fetch(pdfform).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());
const zip = new JSZip();

for (const element of csvData){

const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(formPdfBytes);
const form = pdfDoc.getForm();
const accountNum = form.getTextField("Account Number");
const dob = form.getTextField("Date of Birth");
// etc

form.getCheckBox("box").check();
accountNum.setText(element["Account Number"]);
dob.setText(element["DOB"]);
// etc

if (element["Code"] === "123") { //this gets skipped in large files
    form.getCheckBox("123").check();
}

const pdfBytes = await pdfDoc.save();
zip.file(fileName, pdfBytes, { binary: true }); //filename is unique name made of fields
  

count++; //counter to check for end of loop to save all pdfs to zip

if (count === csvData.length) {
    zip.generateAsync({ type: "blob" }).then(function (content) {
      saveAs(content, "pdfs.zip");
    });
  }
}
```

I only have this issue in large datasets. Smaller ones check the box fine. It's only this statement, if I remove it from if statement it executes without issue. I even have a large `switch` statement the executes fine. I think pdfs are being saved and placed in zip asynchronously.  I've tried wrapping the if statement in a `Promise` but then the zip is empty when downloaded.

How do I ensure that the code in the if statement completes before saving and zipping the PDFs?

Edit: Changed to `for of` loop because of comment. Still skipping over the statement. I've tried putting `await` in front of the commands in if block but to no avail.

Comment: You cannot use a forEach loop as an async loop. You can instead use a for-of loop.

Comment: I changed it but it's still skipping the statement.

Answer (score 0):

So there wasn't an issue after all. There were rows with duplicates that matched name and date but code was different. It was being overridden since code in if statement it was alphabetically first and `fileName` did not have the code as part of the string. Now I have to figure out how to filter out those duplicates but prefer this code over others.